# Why is the header of my calendar control in a different position than the calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a calendar placed in with absolute positioning, but the header isn't staying with the calendar itself.

[image]

The HTML/CSS is the same as other calendar controls on the page which seem to be working fine.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:Calendar>
```

CSS:

```
.auto-style2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 146px;
            left: 642px;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 430px;
        }
```

If I try to move the calendar or the header, they both move at the same time but still away from each other.

What's causing this?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing the actual HTML generated and the definition for `auto-style2` in your CSS file.

Comment: Where can I find this CSS file? I just did a search for a css file and couldn't find anything. @Icarus

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of a CSS layout and positioning problem.  As @Icarus, we need to see the HTML source, and any style sheets.

Comment: You probably have a `float:right` somewhere that is causing the problem. The header is a nested `table` so look for that in the CSS.

Comment: I couldn't find `float` anywhere in the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have defined my calendar for a recent project:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calStartDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="184px" Width="200px" OnSelectionChanged="calStart_SelectionChanged">
                            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#5FD367" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
                            <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
                            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <TitleStyle BackColor="#005555" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        </asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: I think the issue comes up when I change to Absolute positioning. Which I need to do to move the calendar to the correct place on the page, otherwise I can only have everything in one vertical layout.

Comment: Fair enough. I used a table to help position my calendars. Ran into pretty much the same issue because I had two calendars on the same page that needed to be beside each other. Ran into lots of formatting issues, and tried a table which ended up being the solution. However, I'm not sure that will work in your case.